# python's string is unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode

What does `Unicode characters` in python 3 string mean?

> Since Python 3.0, the language features a str type that contain
>   Unicode characters, meaning any string created using "unicode rocks!",
>   'unicode rocks!', or the triple-quoted string syntax is stored as
>   Unicode

from python doc.

for a string `abc`, does Python holds [61, 62, 63] in memory? 
(since `a` is U+0061)

Does unicode character mean unicode codepoints?

Comment: @hop Because it changes how you need to handle the strings.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: how so? the internals of how strings are stored in memory are kept from the user specifically so you don't have to know them in order to use strings. in fact, how strings are stored internally is dependent on the implementation and can vary even with CPython, depending on how it is compiled.

Comment: @hop The question is whether `text[index]` is guaranteed to return a *code point* or whether it may return half of a surrogate pair.

Comment: @eugene: if you are "just curious", you should start by better understanding what unicode is and what an encoding is. After that, this question will be trivial. I'm voting to close.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: 1) how did you parse that from the OP's question. 2) the docs as quoted in the question specifically mention "unicode characters" 3) your question presupposes a specific encoding (namely utf-16) which is no relevant and my not be the one that's used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does unicode character mean unicode codepoints?

Yes and no. It depends on the version of python, and how it was built.

For versions 2.2 to 3.2 inclusive, python supported both narrow and wide unicode builds (see [PEP-261](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0261/)). On a narrow build, the unicode range is restricted to the [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane):

```
Python 3.2.6 (default, Feb 21 2016, 12:42:00)
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sys.maxunicode
65535
```

and so characters outside this range have to represented as a [surrogate pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description):

```
>>> s = ''
>>> ord(s)
128556
>>> len(s)
2
```

With the introduction of [PEP-0393](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/), narrow builds are no longer supported in python3, and so one character is always equivalent to one code-point:

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Mar 3 2016, 09:29:07)
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sys.maxunicode
1114111
>>> s = ''
>>> ord(s)
128556
>>> len(s)
1
```